# Does addJavascriptInterface() rely upon getClass()?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-source, dalvik

I have tried to trace through the code to see how `addJavascriptInterface()` on `WebView` is implemented, but it dives into `native` code, which basically cripples my ability to grok what is going on.

Specifically, I am trying to determine if the JNI(?) means by which `addJavascriptInterface()` arranges to call back into Java code relies upon `getClass()` as part of a reflection strategy, to map method references in JavaScript source to the implementations in Java. I would assume that it has to, and [maybe I am searching in the wrong place](http://androidxref.com/source/search?q=&defs=&refs=getClass&path=&hist=&project=frameworks&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper), but I am not seeing it.

Can anyone point me to the code where the injected Java objects are used, so we can see how that is implemented?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I mean using `getClass()` on the object passed to `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Comment: Another hint that it probably does use reflection: it requires a -keep ProGuard rule.

Comment: Have you tried to implement a JavaScriptInterface instance, and set a breakpoint in one of its methods and have JavaScript in the browser call that method? Examining the stack trace of that call when the breakpoint hits may be enlightening.

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston: Well, I can't set a breakpoint on `getClass()` itself, unless I rig things up with the Android source attached to Eclipse (which is possible, just not something I've needed to mess with). Setting a breakpoint elsewhere might lead me in the direction of where this stuff is in the code, but it won't provide an answer directly. Good ideas, though -- I'll try that stuff today.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Btw, what does [your location](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) mean that you are in "Space"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code that I think you're after is found in `external/webkit/Source/WebCore/bridge/jni/`.  There are two main subdirectories there, `jsc` and `v8` representing the two Javascript engines Android has used.  Since V8 is the engine that's been used most recently and for some time, we'll stick with that.

I'm assuming you were able to successfully trace the Java side of the code to get from `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()` down to `BrowserFrame.nativeAddJavaScriptInterface()`, I'll leave those details out.  The native side is picked up by `AddJavaScriptInterface()` in `external/webkit/Source/WebKit/android/jni/WebCoreFrameBridge.cpp`, where the Java object passed in by the application is finally bound to the WebKit frame with `bindToWindowObject()`.

> I am trying to determine if the JNI means by which addJavascriptInterface() arranges to call back into Java code relies upon getClass() as part of a reflection strategy

The short answer is yes.  They use a lot of wrappers around traditional JNI code, but if you look inside them the accessors on the `JNIEnv` for doing reflection are present.  The wrappers they've created in V8 are:

`external/webkit/Source/WebCore/bridge/jni/v8/JavaInstanceJobjectV8.cpp`
`external/webkit/Source/WebCore/bridge/jni/v8/JavaClassJobjectV8.cpp`
`external/webkit/Source/WebCore/bridge/jni/v8/JavaMethodJobjectV8.cpp`

Going back to `WebCoreFrameBridge.cpp`, before that object the application passed in is bound, the `jobject` originally handed into the native code via JNI is wrapped in a `JavaInstance` class, and then converted to an `NPObject`, which is the final object bound to WebKit.  The source for the V8 NPObject is at:
`external/webkit/Source/WebCore/bridge/jni/v8/JavaNPObjectV8.cpp`

We can see in the `NPObject` implementation that the calls always extract the `JavaInstance` back out and call methods there.  If you look at examples like `JavaNPObjectHasMethod()` or `JavaNPObjectInvoke`, you'll notice the following line appear frequently:

`instance->getClass()->methodsNamed(name)`

This returns the `JavaClass` wrapper they've created, but if you look into the `JavaClassJobjectV8` constructor and associated methods you'll see those familiar reflection calls to the Java object using the `JNIEnv` (including the **actual** JNI `getClass()` call into Dalvik).

So when a method is called by the bound WebKit frame, it finds the associated `NPObject`, which extracts its `JavaInstance` wrapper, which in turn uses JNI reflection to get access to the Java methods.  The chain of custody here is a little harder to follow, so let me know if what's already provided is sufficient to answer your questions.

Comment: Excellent writeup! I hadn't realized that the `external/` projects contained Android-specific hacks like this -- I thought they were closer to pure upstream code. Unfortunately, this means that my current "Hail Mary" attempt to close the `addJavascriptInterface()` security leak is shot as a result. But, better to find that out sooner rather than later, to rummage around my hat again and see if I can find a rabbit. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @CommonsWare did you ever find a rabbit here? Looking around to see if anyone came up with a solution for plugging the security leak on versions of android before 4.2

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: "did you ever find a rabbit here?" -- I live a rabbit-free existence, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got:

```
WebView wv = ...;
wv.addJavascriptInterface(object, name);
```

this goes to:

```
public void addJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name) {
    checkThread();
    mProvider.addJavascriptInterface(object, name);
}
```

`mProvider` is an interface of type `WebViewProvider` as it is declared in in `WebView` class:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Private internal stuff
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

private WebViewProvider mProvider;
```

The only method I can see that instantiates it is `ensureProviderCreated()`:

```
private void ensureProviderCreated() {
    checkThread();
    if (mProvider == null) {
        // As this can get called during the base class constructor chain, pass the minimum
        // number of dependencies here; the rest are deferred to init().
        mProvider = getFactory().createWebView(this, new PrivateAccess());
    }
}
```

`getFactory()` is implemented as:

```
private static synchronized WebViewFactoryProvider getFactory() {
    return WebViewFactory.getProvider();
}
```

[`getProvider()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/webkit/WebViewFactory.java#WebViewFactory.getProvider%28%29) is implemented as:

```
static synchronized WebViewFactoryProvider getProvider() {
    // For now the main purpose of this function (and the factory abstraction) is to keep
    // us honest and minimize usage of WebViewClassic internals when binding the proxy.
    if (sProviderInstance != null) return sProviderInstance;

    sProviderInstance = getFactoryByName(DEFAULT_WEB_VIEW_FACTORY);
    if (sProviderInstance == null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(LOGTAG, "Falling back to explicit linkage");
        sProviderInstance = new WebViewClassic.Factory();
    }
    return sProviderInstance;
}
```

[`getFactoryByName()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/webkit/WebViewFactory.java#WebViewFactory.getFactoryByName%28java.lang.String%29) is implemented as:

```
private static WebViewFactoryProvider getFactoryByName(String providerName) {
    try {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(LOGTAG, "attempt to load class " + providerName);
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(providerName);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(LOGTAG, "instantiating factory");
        return (WebViewFactoryProvider) c.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "error loading " + providerName, e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "error loading " + providerName, e);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "error loading " + providerName, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and here is where it uses Reflection. If an exception occurs during instantiating the custom class, [`WebViewClassic.Factory()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/webkit/WebViewClassic.java#WebViewClassic.Factory) will be used instead. Here is how it is implemented:

```
static class Factory implements WebViewFactoryProvider,  WebViewFactoryProvider.Statics {
    @Override
    public String findAddress(String addr) {
        return WebViewClassic.findAddress(addr);
    }
    @Override
    public void setPlatformNotificationsEnabled(boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            WebViewClassic.enablePlatformNotifications();
        } else {
            WebViewClassic.disablePlatformNotifications();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Statics getStatics() { return this; }

    @Override
    public WebViewProvider createWebView(WebView webView, WebView.PrivateAccess privateAccess) {
        return new WebViewClassic(webView, privateAccess);
    }

    @Override
    public GeolocationPermissions getGeolocationPermissions() {
        return GeolocationPermissionsClassic.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public CookieManager getCookieManager() {
        return CookieManagerClassic.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public WebIconDatabase getWebIconDatabase() {
        return WebIconDatabaseClassic.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public WebStorage getWebStorage() {
        return WebStorageClassic.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public WebViewDatabase getWebViewDatabase(Context context) {
        return WebViewDatabaseClassic.getInstance(context);
    }
}
```

Now go back to `mProvider = getFactory().createWebView(this, new PrivateAccess());` where `getFactory()` is either the custom class (by reflection) or `WebViewClassic.Factory`.

`WebViewClassic.Factory#createWebView()` returns [`WebViewClassic`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/webkit/WebViewClassic.java#WebViewClassic) which is a sub-type of `mProvider`'s type.

`WebViewClassic#addJavascriptInterface` is implemented as:

```
/**
 * See {@link WebView#addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)}
 */
@Override
public void addJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name) {
    if (object == null) {
        return;
    }
    WebViewCore.JSInterfaceData arg = new WebViewCore.JSInterfaceData();
    arg.mObject = object;
    arg.mInterfaceName = name;
    mWebViewCore.sendMessage(EventHub.ADD_JS_INTERFACE, arg);
}
```

I think, this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: My interpretation of the question: Is reflection used when javascript communicates back, after a query is floated using `BrowserFrame#stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(String)`? Looking at your answer, I think my interpretation is way off.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified more originally (and just did in an edit): I am interested in knowing if `getClass()` will be called on the object passed into `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is  more of a comment than an answer, but I can't add a stacktrace in comments. So here it goes:

When setting a breakpoint in an Object that servers as a JavaScript Interface implementation, this is a sample stack-trace I get:

```
16> WebViewCoreThread@830034675584, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
      at com.mediaarc.player.books.model.pagesource.service.EPubPageSourceService$JS.JSReady(EPubPageSourceService.java:1752)
      at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:-1)
      at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:-1)
      at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:814)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It starts in Java (`Thread.run` --> `handleMessage`). Then it disappears into Native code (`nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue`) and it comes out again in Java (`nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue` --> `JSReady`).

This stack is from a Nexus 10 running 4.3.

There is something going on in the Native Layer that moves the execution from within a call to nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue directly to the Java method of the JavaScriptInterface instance in Java.

Nowadays, the JavaScriptInterface need to annotate each method that it publishes to JavaScript (`@JavaScriptInterface` method annotation). Maybe this generates some JNI bridges on the fly calling from Native into Java.

I wonder how this stack-trace would have looked like on an older device where the `@JavaScriptInterface` annotations were not necessary.

Comment: On Android 4.1, the stack trace is even less informative, jumping from `WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick()` straight into my method. And, while I seem to be able to tell Eclipse that I want a breakpoint on `getClass()`, it doesn't actually suspend the thread -- it just slows things down.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on a method makes everything wicked slow. There is no way of overriding the 'public Class<?> getClass()', even when using interfaces/Proxy/InvocationHandler classes. To my knowledge, there is no 'clean' way to get information about an instance without calling its getClass() method. From then on, you could then generate, based on Method information, the appropriate JNI bindings to call into Java directly.

Answer (score 0):

from [Understanding Android's webview addjavascriptinterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962150/understanding-androids-webview-addjavascriptinterface) : "The method WebView.addJavascriptInterface sends a message to an instance of WebViewCore:

mWebViewCore.sendMessage(EventHub.ADD_JS_INTERFACE, arg); In WebViewCore.java there are a bunch of overloaded methods called sendMessage , but we don't really need to know which exactly is being called, since they do pretty much the same thing. There's even a nice comment to give us a hint that we're in the right place! All of them are delegating to an instance of EventHub which is some inner class. This method turns out to be synchronized, and is sending a message to an instance of Handler, which is a good indication that this is probably running in another thread, but for completeness sake, let's find out!

That Handler is instantiated in EventHub.transferMessages which is called from WebViewCore.initialize . There are a few more hops here, but eventually I found out that this is called from run in WebCoreThread (subclass of Runnable), which is instantiated along with a new Thread right here ." instantiated along with a new Thread right here ."

```
  synchronized (WebViewCore.class) {
            if (sWebCoreHandler == null) {
                // Create a global thread and start it.
                Thread t = new Thread(new WebCoreThread());
                t.setName(THREAD_NAME);
                t.start();
                try {
                    WebViewCore.class.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Caught exception while waiting for thread " +
                           "creation.");
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
            }
        }
```

In other words, this could be the chain of calls in my opinion:

android.webkit.WebViewClassic

```
 4159    @Override
4160    public void More ...addJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name) {
4161
4162        if (object == null) {
4163            return;
4164        }
4165        WebViewCore.JSInterfaceData arg = new WebViewCore.JSInterfaceData();
4166
4167        arg.mObject = object;
4168        arg.mInterfaceName = name;
4169
4170        // starting with JELLY_BEAN_MR1, annotations are mandatory for enabling access to
4171        // methods that are accessible from JS.
4172        if (mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
4173            arg.mRequireAnnotation = true;
4174        } else {
4175            arg.mRequireAnnotation = false;
4176        }
4177        mWebViewCore.sendMessage(EventHub.ADD_JS_INTERFACE, arg);
4178    }
```

android.webkit.WebViewCore

```
 static class JSInterfaceData {
827         Object mObject;
828         String mInterfaceName;
829         boolean mRequireAnnotation;
830     }
```

java.lang.Object

```
 37 public class Object {
38 
39     private static native void registerNatives();
40     static {
41         registerNatives();
42     }
```

Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class. The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:

```
 Number n = 0; 
Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
```

Returns: The Class object that represents the runtime class of this object. See also: The Java Language Specification, Third Edition (15.8.2 Class Literals)

```
 64 
65     public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

From a Dalvik's perspective I think you are just registering a JNI callback via findClass like this from [JNIHelp.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/bf0cce6d471ffcd65161eca6e027e1b66f02f054/libnativehelper/JNIHelp.c) :

```
 /*
 * Register native JNI-callable methods.
 *
 * "className" looks like "java/lang/String".
 */
int jniRegisterNativeMethods(JNIEnv* env, const char* className,
    const JNINativeMethod* gMethods, int numMethods)
{
    jclass clazz;

    LOGV("Registering %s natives\n", className);
    clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        LOGE("Native registration unable to find class '%s', aborting\n",
            className);
        abort();
    }

    if ((*env)->RegisterNatives(env, clazz, gMethods, numMethods) < 0) {
        LOGE("RegisterNatives failed for '%s', aborting\n", className);
        abort();
    }

    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, clazz);
    return 0;
}
```

In conclusion my idea is derived from [Native Libraries](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html):

```
//Get jclass with env->FindClass
```

so maybe FindClass could be used instead of getClass...