# Javascript interface not working in release build

Tags: javascript, android, jenkins, webview, release-builds

I have a Webview with some Javascript interface

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    void buttonClick() {
        listener.onButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

This is how it's added to the view

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
```

In debug build the listener is working.

In release build, made by Jenkins, it doesn't work.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "terminal_${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It shouldn't be related to Proguard, because minify is disabled.

I tried different [Proguard settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271485/android-proguard-javascript-interface-fail?rq=1) anyway, it didn't helped.

How to make it work in release build?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a solve for this? I'm having the exact same issue, these functions are being removed from my release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Making the interface method public resolved the issue

```
public void buttonClick() {
        listener.onButtonClicked();
    }
```

> If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the
>   @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available
>   to your JavaScript (the method must also be public).
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript